# automatically resolve numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hi I have some binary Files created in IDL (Interactive Data Language) which can be read through scipy using

```
scipy.io.readsav
```

In particular I used it as follow

```
data = scipy.io.readsav("input.sav", python_dict=True)
```

so that the output is a standard python dictionary. In particular the output I can access the numpy.recarray which is stored in the dictionary

```
du = data.keys()
duV = data[du[0]]
```

so duV now is a recarray. I don't know a priori the variables and the names which are stored in the recarray. I can access the names of the variables as

```
names = duV.dtype.names
```

Now suppose that names is equal to

```
('V', 'T', 'THETA', 'ERR')
```

I would like to find an automatically procedure to read all the variables with the corresponding names, i.e. something which automatically do as

```
v = duV.field('V')
t = duV.field('T')
```

ect. ect. So I would like to create variables which are named as the names of the recarray

Comment: Why don't you just access them as `duV.field('V')`?

Comment: Because I don't know a priori the names of the field and I would like to define a function which independently of the names of names resolve the recarray. I hope I explain my self

Comment: But you have the names in `duV.dtype.names`, so you know them: `duV.field(duV.dtype.names[0])`

Comment: Sorry I think I have not explained my self. I know I can loop over names but how can I make the variables created to be named as names? that is NAMES[0] = duV.field(duV.dtype.names[0])

Comment: I understand what you want. I'm trying to explain that you don't *need to*. You already have a good data structure. What you want is considered bad practice. Assume, you did what you want. How would you pass that variable to a function? You don't have a fixed variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put all the fields in to global variables, you can do:

```
for name in duV.dtype.names:
    globals()[name.lower()] = duV.field(name)
```

Comment: Thank you this resolved my question. Maybe as noted by Avaris this is not a good programming practice (in a more general perspective) but for my purpose this is what I needed.